# The intersection of linear subspaces is non empty if...

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I am interested in the following question, suppose in $R^3$ we have $n$ hyperspaces defined as $a_ix+b_i y+c_i z-d_i<0$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$. Are there any conditions on $(a_i,b_,c_i,d_i)$, under which the intersection of these hyperspaces is non-empty?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As a vector equation, $\left(a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i\right) \bullet \left(x,y,z,-1\right) = 0 $ for every $i$. So we obtain a matrix
$$
\left(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b},\mathbf{c},\mathbf{d}\right)
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
-1
\end{pmatrix}
= \mathbf{0}
$$

That is, the intersection of subspaces is non-empty iff $(x,y,z,-1)^T$ is in the kernel of $\left(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b},\mathbf{c},\mathbf{d}\right)$ for some $x,y,z$. So compute the kernel: if it contains $(x,y,z,w)^T$ with $w \neq 0 $, then the intersection is non-empty; set $w=-1$ to find it.

Comment: I am asking about the intersection of \textbf{hyperspaces} with the inequality!!! sign, rather than the intersection of hyperplanes with the equality sign :)

Comment: Whoops! Right, then you're talking about open half-spaces. They intersect in a convex hull (possibly with vertices at infinity). There's a fast O(nlogn) algorithm for finding the convex hull from the open half-spaces, but I don't think there's an algebraic condition for being non-empty.